# Type mismatch : cannot convert from element type Object to String

Tags: java

I have a dropdown list that I want to fill via a database
I show  code

```
private String maValeur; 
private List<SelectItem> mesElements;

            public String getMaValeur() {
                return maValeur;
            }
            public void setMaValeur(String maValeur) {
                this.maValeur = maValeur;
            }
            public List getMaliste()
            {
                ArrayList<String> unelist = new ArrayList();

                try { 
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
                     String serverName = "localhost";
                        String mydatabase = "gestionticket";
                        String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName +":3306"+ "/"+ mydatabase; // a JDBC url
                         String user = "root";
                         String pass = "";


                     java.sql.Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
                             Statement instruction = (Statement) ((java.sql.Connection) connection).createStatement();



                             String sql = "select * from gestionticket.client" ;    
                                ResultSet resultat  = (ResultSet) instruction.executeQuery(sql);

                                while(resultat.next()){
                                    String nom=resultat.getString("nom").toString();
                                    unelist.add(nom);

                                }
                    //session.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return (List) unelist;
            }
            public List<SelectItem> getMesElements() {
                 if (mesElements == null) {
                     mesElements = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
                     for (String val : getMaliste()) {
                         mesElements.add(new SelectItem(val));
                     }
                 }
                return mesElements;
            }
```

by an error msg appears at line level

```
for (String val : getMaliste() {
                   mesElements.add(new SelectItem(val));
               }
```

Here is the msg error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String

if you have any idea about this compilation error; help me

Comment: What are `getMaliste()` and `mesElements`?

Comment: Is it just a typo that you forgot the last `)` in the for loop?

Comment: @BalusC It could be happening on either one of the lines though, right?

Comment: this should work only if `getMaliste()` gives you a list of string

Comment: Here is the complete method I have to change the question

Comment: @BalusC What if `mesElements` is a `List<String>`?

Comment: hey the code is totally messed up the thing is imports the not correct so i dont thing the list will get populated anyway

Comment: @BalusC  This list is used to fill dropdown

Comment: @M.Sharma at you have an idea how to fill a dropdowlist in jsf

Comment: @BalusC tell me exactly how to gonna populate the list if the connections in never established(will never if the imports are not correct and even if you say the imports are correct then there is never a need to caste) and resultset is fetched?

Comment: @BalusC ya may be he got it too early

Comment: @BalusC  thank you very much for your answer and I'll get otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method has a [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) in the signature,

```
public List getMaliste()
```

should be

```
public List<String> getMaliste()
```

And don't cast to the raw-type at the return,

```
return unelist;
```

Comment: I change the method but its not working java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to javax.faces.model.SelectItem

Comment: @user3766709 That fixes your first error, which line is giving your new error?

Comment: This `ArrayList<String> unelist = new ArrayList();` should be `ArrayList<String> unelist = new ArrayList<>();`.

Comment: Since you are not even sure of WHY and WHAT of compilation errors, I recommend investing some time in learning the basics first as also suggested by @BalusC. Also the way you have written the code is very annoying and hard to read.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch  thank you very much for your answer it workkk

Answer (score 1):

**ERROR :- Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String.**
You will always get this error whenever you try to convert a Object type to String type as Object type is higher on class hierarchy, i.e. to say Object is the super class of String type(and eventually all other classes in Java).

**Solution to this Error :**

Whenever you are having any method that is returning any Object type but you need to store that as s String type, then append toString() method on that Object.
For example:

```
public class ObjectToString {
    public List<String> getName() {
        List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Andrew Smith");
        list.add("Jen Hawkins");
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ObjectToString ots=new ObjectToString();
        String names=ots.getName().toString();
        System.out.println(names);
    }
}
```

Here the return type of the method getName() is List type and you are assigning  it's content to a String type variable in main(), which is not possible unless you use toString() method on getName().